# Simple Client Manager Soft - C# with Visual Studio or Java with Eclipse?

Tags: java, c#, python, eclipse, visual-studio-2012

)

Im currently studying Computer Science, and I know a bit of Java, C, C# and Python.

At the same time Im working part time in a Book Store, just selling books.
Lately Ive been thinking that we, in the library, could use the help of a small piece of software to keep track of our clients. So I decided to program it.

I have the basic idea of how to code it in mind; But I can not decide what to use; It would be one of my first programs with a (simple) visual interface.

So, what do you advice guys? C# and using VS, or Eclipse with Java, using one of the Visual Interface plugins.

Or maybe you have a better idea in mind, If so, I would love to hear it :)

Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: java is practically useless [for desktop software]. Use C# and WPF.

Comment: Asking for an opinion is not the best first question you could think of. Did you read the [help]?

Comment: @Steve -> But the question I had was not one of the how much is 2+2 kind... The question I asked has many valid answers, so we could say every answer here would be an opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps not the best question to ask on SO as it's bound to get opinions rather than answers, with this in mind, I will give you my *opinionated answer.*

As your first real life application, it's probably best you go with something you're somewhat familiar with, either that or find a solution with simple, quick set up guides for beginners.

Both of the languages and environments you mentioned have these.

Myself,  I would use C#. It's always been my go to language to demonstrate some real world problems as it's generally quite quick to get going. Once you download Visual Studio and start writing code, it all just comes together. There is plenty of material available at MSDN which has examples of code with how it should be used, there are even some tutorials on there, I believe one of them is actually a book shop tool.

Have a look there and see what you find.

Ultimately, you'll likely have to make a decision as to the language and development style / environment that you like, but for now, you have one biased opinion from a happy and content .NET developer.

Comment: Thank you Bara'thorn for your answer :) ; It was really insightful.  I think I'll go with C# in this one :)

Yap, and opinions from experienced guys was what I was looking for, but what's wrong with asking for insightful opinions? (-5 votes in my question :P).

Thanks ;)

Comment: StackOverflow is really best used as a place to ask specific questions, normally ones to which there is more or less correct answer or solution to the question. While the question, I believe is a good one, it has not been worded in a way which there is a correct answer, it's very open to interpretation and preference of the person writing.

Answer (score 0):

The first question here is which one you are more comfortable with, C# or Java and the required additional toolkits for GUI programming such as swing. Since you are going to make a kind of experimental small application you don't really need many bells and whistles of these technologies so whatever you pick you will be satisfied with. If your application is going to be run on any OS other than Windows (or multiple OSs) I strongly recommend you to use Java with whatever IDE you like. NetBeans and Intellij Idea are as good as Eclipse (even if not better) in desktop application programming but this is not important and just a matter of personal preference. But if you are going to develop just for Windows I think Visual Studio with C# will make a very satisfying experience for you and in my opinion you will spend less time developing the app if you go with the MS offering (This is the opinion of a long time Java fan)

Comment: Thanks @Hessam :) 
I feel a bit more comfortable using Java, but as the program will be used only on Windows Systems, and everyone is recommending C# Ill go with that for this small project.
Thanks for the NetBeans and Intellij recommendation, I will keep an eye on that ;)

Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO try [Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/) (with jQuery) or if you know Excel - use it.

Building a working UI, that behaves as you would expect can be hard (read: time consuming) at first. Personally I find C# really easy, but that is because I have years of experience. General rule is that you learn by failed attempts and remember : expert has failed more then beginner has ever tried.

Comment: Thanks Margus, I will check out the JavaScript+JQuery option closely ;). And thanks for your encouraging words "expert has failed more then beginner has ever tried", really inspiring ;)